# How to configure line length for VS Code python Sort Imports in user settings?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using the [Sort Imports](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_sort-imports) function of the Python extension for VS Code. I'd like to configure the line length for this to 100; however, I've been unable to properly set this in my `settings.json` file. From the documentation, it seems like `"python.sortImports.args": ["-l", "100"]` should work, but it's giving me an error: `Invalid patch string: Skipped 1 files`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowdays, it's adding:

```py
    "isort.args": ["-l", "100"],
```

to your settings file.

Answer (score 7):

There is a known bug with using Sort Imports on `__init__.py` files. Here is the full solution to put in vscode's `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
"python.sortImports.args": ["-ns", "__init__.py", "-l", "100"],
```

Comment: UPDATE: This setting will be removed soon. Use `isort.args` instead.(2)